# What's recommended for the number of users to use in qualitative and quantitative usability studies?

Tags: sample-size, hypothesis-testing

It was recommended to me on the [User Interface Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/whats-recommended-for-the-number-of-users-to-use-in-qualitative-and-quantitative) that I also ask this question here. So....

I'm currently rebuilding our entire intranet from scratch, mostly because the tech behind is out-dated and it has been proved that a lot of information is difficult to find.

Though that is beside the point, what I am wondering is what would be the optimum amount of users to use for qualitative and quantitative testing with a userbase of around 1000 users?

Is there a general rule of thumb for both based on the total number of users you have? or is it just say 5 for qualitative and 10 for quantitative?

What would be the best approach?

Comment: What would be the goals of qualitative and quantitative testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an exact answer to your question (which is kind of not understandable enough for conrete answers, see Srikant's comment), but a more general one:
If you want to do statistical testing on your data it is advisable to make sure that your sample conforms to the **[central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)**. That is, the distribution of sample means from which your sample is drawn is normal (i.e., bell-shaped). Then you can use a lot of nice methods (as long as the other assumptions are met) on your data that try to estimate population parameters from your sample. **A rule of thumb about the central limit theorem is that you need at least 30 participants (or 20, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276/how-large-should-a-sample-be-for-a-given-estimation-technique-and-parameters))**.
My advice: If you think that 10 could be enough, use at least 20.

For qualitative testing, I would guess, just use participants until you get a picture of what the issues are. Ask a couple of people to test your stuff and ask them to tell you their impression. If they agree to some degree, there you go. I think 5 is a good starting point (caveat: this is a non-theoretically answer, based on my stomach, and I just had lunch).

If you are interested in polls from your sample, [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-do-you-decide-the-sample-size-when-polling-a-large-population) could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Jakob Nielsen [recommends testing with five users](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000319.html) for optimal results. This assertion has been challenged a few times, both empirically and theoretically, but generally seems to hold quite well.